# How to change the password via ssh on airOS8 for UBNT WA v8.x boards

Tags: networking, ssh, passwords, policy, ubiquity

How can I change the user's password over ssh connection (not via browser interface) on the UBNT (Ubiquity Network) device, more specifically airOS8 WA v8.x board?

I want to avoid the ridiculous restriction imposed by their web interface on the password complexity (the only thing they don't require in the password is the unicorn's blood). I don't feel comfortable with someone else telling me what my passwords should look like (for my own well being, of course), so I'd like to change it via ssh connection, where this restriction is not being imposed.

I followed the [discussion on their forums](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/airMAX-AC/8-3-admin-password-requirements/td-p/1965739), which is just a useless bike-shedding over the opinions if the developers should impose such restrictions (without the switch to turn that off) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this and wanted to share with others, who need to do the same thing.

First, log in to your device over an ssh connection. Then, issue a `passwd` command to change your password. If you now just reboot your device, the new password won't be saved, so read on.

Next, you need to copy the new password hash to a file named `/var/tmp/system.cfg`. So, first, type `cat /etc/passwd`, to see the new password hash, which should look something like this:

`ubnt:$1$ssssssss$hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh:0:0:Administrator:/etc/persistent:/bin/sh`

where `ssssssss` is the Salt and `hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh` is the Hash of the new password. We need to copy all that to the `/var/tmp/system.cfg` file, so type:

`vi /var/tmp/system.cfg` and in there, find the line that starts with `users.1.password=` and change it to be like this (press 'I' for Insert operation):

`users.1.password=$1$ssssssss$hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh`

where Salt and Hash will be something randomly generated. When you finish changing that line, press Escape key and then save/quit the file (pressing colon, 'w', 'q' and Enter key, like ':wq')

Once you're back in the shell, type `save` to save this configuration permanently and then type `reboot` to check if your password survived the reboot process.

That should be it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, but much better is to use a hash of default password `ubnt`, to get it, just run `grep users.1.password /var/etc/default.cfg`

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question? It asks how to change the password, not how to reset it to default.

Comment: @Miaden B. You right, first reset it to default and next change it to one that you want to it via UI.